# Is there any problem with this code?

Tags: android

It produce the stopped unexpectedly problem when I push the search button.

```
public class beautiful extends Activity {
    ImageView radar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
      this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.beautiful);

    radar = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.radar);
    Button search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.magnifier);
    ImageView text = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    MediaPlayer siren = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.siren);

    search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Thread counter = new Thread(new Runnable(){

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    try{
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                        radar.setImageResource(R.drawable.radar_new_full);
                        Thread.sleep(3000);
                        radar.setImageResource(R.drawable.radar_new_50);
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                        radar.setImageResource(R.drawable.radar_new_found);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    finally{

                    }
                }

            });
            counter.start();
        }
    });
}
```

Here are the LogCat warnings:

07-07 17:36:17.298: WARN/dalvikvm(274): threadid=15: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
07-07 17:36:17.306: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274): Uncaught handler: thread Thread-8 exiting due to uncaught exception
07-07 17:36:17.306: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
07-07 17:36:17.306: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:2683)
07-07 17:36:17.306: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at android.view.ViewRoot.requestLayout(ViewRoot.java:557)
07-07 17:36:17.306: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:7918)
07-07 17:36:17.306: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:7918)
07-07 17:36:17.306: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:7918)
07-07 17:36:17.306: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:7918)
07-07 17:36:17.306: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:271)
07-07 17:36:17.306: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at example.beautiful$1$1.run(beautiful.java:46)
07-07 17:36:17.306: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)

Comment: Always paste all relevant LogCat output for any error you want help with. Some people may be able to find out what is wrong by eyeballing your code but it is a lot easier to just read your error log (which specifically tells you what is wrong). This can be viewed in the "LogCat" view in Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks, check out gopal's answer. You are calling UI methods (setimageresource) from a non-UI thread. "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views"

Comment: OK thanks. I read it. The big problem is that I don't understand this AsyncTask very good. There are only examples with downloading the pics, what doesn't need for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about ANR Dialog [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html) and how to update UI from other thread [Painless Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove **@Override** above the **public void run()**.

Comment: Tried, but the same :( Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Put some print statements here and there or breakpoints, whichever you prefer.
Trace down which line is the one which causes the error, try putting try-catch statements around it to have a clear idea of what the error is - then it would be easier to solve the error (Shortly debug)

- just an advice

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
super.onCreate(icicle);
//do sth...
}
```

Comment: Bundle saveInstanceState != Bundle icicle?

Comment: Well i prefer you to use Bundle icicle because it's more useful in UI mode than saveInstanceState , This my personal experience.